# Inverse function that does not have a inverse function given by an integral

Tags: analysis

I have the following exercise:

1) Consider $X = \left( (C[0,1], \mathbb{R}), d_{\infty} \right) $ and 
$Y = \left( (C^{1}[0,1], \mathbb{R}), d_{\infty} \right) $ and the operator 
$\Phi:X \rightarrow Y$ given by
$$
\Phi(f)(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(s)\;ds, \;\;\forall x \in [0,1].
$$
Show that

(a) $\Phi$ is uniformly continuous;

(b) $\Phi$ has an inverse $\Phi^{-1}$;

(c) $\Phi^{-1}$ is not continuous;

(d) Consider now $X$ and 
$Z = \left( (C^{1}[0,1], \mathbb{R}), d_{1, \infty} \right) $, where $d_{1, \infty} (f,g)= d_{\infty}(f,g) + d_{\infty}(f',g')$, and the same operator $\Phi : X \rightarrow Z$.

With this metric $d_{1, \infty}$, do we take $\Phi^{-1}$ continuous?

So, I know which the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus assures me that $\Phi$ belongs to Y. This implies that $\Phi$ is well defined.

The proof of item (a) I had that
$$
| \Phi(f)(x)-\Phi(f)(y)|=
\Big|\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\;ds - \int_{0}^{y}f(s)\;ds\Big| =\\
\Big|\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\;ds - \int_{0}^{x}f(s)\;ds - \int_{x}^{y}f(s)\;ds\Big|=
\Big|\int_{x}^{y}f(s)\;ds\Big| \leq 
\int_{x}^{y}|f(s)|\;ds.
$$
How $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C[0,1]$, we know that $f$ is bounded, so there is $k \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ that $|f(x)| \leq k, \forall x \in [0,1]$.

Hence 
$$
| \Phi(f)(x)-\Phi(f)(y)| \leq \int_{x}^{y}|f(s)|\;ds \leq \int_{x}^{y}k\;ds = k\int_{x}^{y}\;ds = k|y-x|. 
$$
This implies that $\Phi$ is Lipschitz and hence $\Phi$ is uniformly continuous.

(b)  I know by FTC which for given $f\in X$, we have $\Phi$ such that
$$ \Phi'(f)(x)=
\dfrac{d}{dx} \Phi(f)(x) = 
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x}f(s)\;ds =
f(x), \forall x \in [0,1].$$

That is, the inverse of $\Phi$ is $\Phi^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$ given by $\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(f)) = (\Phi(f))'=f$.

But I don't know how to ensure that $\Phi^{-1}$ is a bijection function

But, I can't figure out to solve (b) (conclusion), (c) and (d).

Comment: For (b), (c), (d), what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Saad for (b) I know by FTC which for given $f \in X$, we have $\Phi$ such that $\Phi' (x) = f(x), \forall x \in [0,1]$. So I need to show that $\Phi^{-1}$ given by $\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(f)) = f(x) \forall x$. I think that is correct by FTC. But I don't have sure and I don't know how to ensure that $\Phi$ is a bijection function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) $\Phi$ is injective but not surjective. For all $f$ we have $\Phi(f)(0) = 0$. Obviously, $\Phi(X)$ is strictly smaller than $Y$. But is true that (I will use another name) $\Psi(f) = f'$ verifies $\forall f\in X: \Psi(\Phi((f)) = f$ and that $\Psi$ is defined in the whole $Y$ (is an extension of $\Phi^{-1}$).

(c) Take a sequence $f_n\in Y$ s.t. $f_n\to f\in Y$ uniformly but $f_n'\not\to   f'$ uniformly.

(d) I will use again the name $\Psi$:
$$
d_{\infty}(\Psi(f),\Psi(g)) = d_{\infty}(f',g')\le d_{1,\infty}(\cdots).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help me.I will focus first on item b. After that I will to (c) and (d). Well, You said for me that
1) $\Phi$ is injective
2) $\Phi$ is not surjective.
3) $\forall f \in X$, we have $\Phi(f)(0) = 0$.
4) $\Phi(X) \subsetneqq Y$.
5) we have an extension $\Psi $ of $\Phi^{-1}$ that $\Psi (\Phi (f)) = f$. 
I can understand 3) and 5). 
The assertive 3) is obvious. And 5) I know that is a FTC but I can't get all.

Comment: I got it the item (b). You said for me defined $\Psi: Y \rightarrow X$ given by $\Psi (f) = f'$. So with this we obtain $\Phi \circ \Psi = Id_{Y}$ and $\Psi \circ \Phi = Id_{X}$. The both we get by FTC. Now, I don't know how sequence $f_n \in Y$ we need to take for show that $\Psi = \Phi^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Comment: @ThiagoAlexandre, see http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-around-differentiation-of-sequences-of-functions/.

Comment: @ThiagoAlexandre, $\Phi \circ\Psi = Id_{Y}$ is actually false (again, because $\Phi(f)(0) = 0$).

Comment: Thanks. I got it.